# Write SQL query so all question choices are in the same JSON object as the answer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table with Questions in it, and the other table with choices to those questions.

If I have 5 questions, and every question has 5 choices, is there a way to write a query so I get one question and all its choices in one JSON object, so I would get 5 objects, and not 25 as I am getting now.

So if I have in table "Questions" a question '5+5=?', with ID=1 and in table "Choices", 5 choices: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 with QUESTION_ID=1. I would like to export it as:
`{"question":"5+5=?", "choice":"1", "choice":"2"...}`
and not `{"question":"5+5=?", "choice":"1"}, {"question":"5+5=?", "choice":"2"}`.

Also `{"question":"5+5=?", "choices":{"choice":"1", "choice":"2"...}}` would be great.

I have tried this query but it only separates choices by comma:

```
SELECT q.question,       
       string_agg(choice, ', ') as answer
FROM question q
join question_choice qc on q.id = qc.question_id
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: You need to tag your backend. There might be different ways for your backend, ie: postgreSQL have built-in Json functions.

Comment: Also, show the table definitions, sample data, expected results and the query you've tried so far...  I also recommend reading this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

`{"question":"5+5=?", "choice":"1", "choice":"2"...}` and `{"choice":"1", "choice":"2"...}` are not allowed in the json type because the same key cannot appear several times in the same json object.

Instead you can get the following result `{"question":"5+5=?", "choices": ["1", "2", ...]}` where the list of choices is a json array with the following query :

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object('question', q.question, 'choices', array_agg(qc.choice))
  FROM question q
 INNER JOIN question_choice qc
    ON q.id = qc.question_id
 GROUP BY q.question ;
```

or you can get the following result `{"question":"5+5=?", "choices": [{"choice": "1"}, {"choice": "2"}, ...]}` where the list of choices is a json array with the following query :

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object('question', q.question, 'choices', array_agg(jsonb_build_object('choice', qc.choice)))
  FROM question q
 INNER JOIN question_choice qc
    ON q.id = qc.question_id
 GROUP BY q.question ;
```